# Does "assistant store manager trainee position" need hyphens?

Tags: punctuation

Is the following sentence clear enough without hyphens?

> He applied for the assistant store manager trainee position.

Or should it be:

> He applied for the 
>   assistant-store-manager-trainee position.

Or for another example,

> I like chocolate chip cookie dough ice cream.

Or:

> I like chocolate-chip-cookie-dough ice cream.

Would you write these with or without the hyphens? Unfortunately, I cannot recast.

I think that in these examples, the inclusion of hyphens is somewhat distracting, and we should write these phrases as presented above (i.e., without any hyphens whatsoever). Do you agree?

Comment: I think you do need hyphens for clarification. But it helps if you can rationalise your sentences so as to limit the number. I might, for example, say : *He applied for the trainee assistant-store-manager position*. (I do think *trainee* should go first). I don't know anything about chocolate, ice-cream etc. I'm trying to kill all that stuff before it kills me.

Comment: Thank you, WS2. I also think that "a $100-million-to-$150-million-a-year industry" needs full hyphenation throughout (as shown in this example), including hyphens on both sides of the word "to". Agreed?

Comment: I think I would just say *a $100 to $150 million-per-year industry*. I don't think you need hyphens either side of the *to*. And you don't need to repeat the word *million*. Everybody knows you are talking in millions. With hyphenation, I would say - let practicality and common sense be your guide.

Comment: I think you need to place "million" after $100 in your example above because $100 could be initially construed as a hundred dollars.

Comment: Well, if I was speaking I would say *a one-hundred to one-hundred and fifty million-per-year industry*. It depends on how formally accurate you want to be.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the compounds are the parenthesized items here,

> (((assistant (store manager)) trainee) position)

and you should use hyphens between the parts of a compound if it is part of a hyphenated compound, you can use from zero to four hyphens.  One hyphen looks best to me.

Similarly, assuming

> ((((chocolate chip) cookie) dough) (ice cream))

which has dough for chocolate-chip cookies, or perhaps

> > (((chocolate chip) (cookie dough)) (ice cream))

which has cookie dough made with chocolate chips.